# Why ng-if doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try use this case:

```
<a href="/products/" ng-if="filterPriceFrom == 0 || filterPriceFrom > 0 && filterPriceTo < 200000" class=" tag">
  {{ filterPriceFrom }} - {{ filterPriceTo }}
  <span ng-click="cleanPriceSlider()" class="tag-close"></span>
</a>
```

and everything works except that part:

```
filterPriceFrom == 0
```

Can anyone explain why???

Comment: Are you sure about the priority of logical operations?

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: you try with ng-if="filterPriceFrom >= 0 && filterPriceTo < 200000"

Comment: @AlonEitan I think it is `ng-if="(filterPriceFrom == 0) || (filterPriceFrom > 0)&& filterPriceTo < 200000)"`?

Comment: also, if you are wanting to ensure it is type checked, use === instead of == but that is up to you.

Comment: @SkullDev It's none of the tow - See Michelem's answer

Comment: I'm try all of these methods, and nothng, i really cant understand it

Comment: can you print to console the values of the elements you are working with? - is it possible that some of these have no value? (or undefined) - it'd help if you add a [mcve] for us to work with

Comment: ng-if="(filterPriceFrom == 0 || filterPriceFrom > 0) && filterPriceTo < 200000"
i need to get this logic

Comment: but first part befor || doesnt work

Comment: @AlexandrDomoryonok Just describe in plain words the condition in which you want this `A` element to be visible or hidden (And add this description in the answer, not as a comment)

Comment: And the value of `filterPriceFrom` is? Is it really `0` or `'0'`? Make sure you prioritize your logical condition and type checking

Comment: Is `filterPriceForm` attached to the $scope? If it isn't, the view can't access it.

Comment: @AlonEitan that is what i wrote, only 1 bracket out (typo) but effectively that is my answer right there... lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
ng-if="filterPriceFrom === 0 || (filterPriceFrom > 0 && filterPriceTo < 200000)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a another scope to calculate Subtract value and pass it to the template.

JS part

```
$scope.filterPriceFrom = 0;
$scope.filterPriceTo = 10;
$scope.Filterval = $scope.filterPriceFrom- $scope.filterPriceTo;
```

Html Part

```
 <a href="/products/" ng-if="filterPriceFrom == 0 || filterPriceFrom > 0 && filterPriceTo < 200000" class=" tag">
 {{Filterval}}
 <span ng-click="cleanPriceSlider()" class="tag-close"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: You're just reproducing the same bug, only calculating the result in the controller side. How is that change that fact that _and everything works except that part:_ `filterPriceFrom == 0`  (As the OP stated)?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oDNbaZ?p=preview)

Condition `filterPriceFrom == 0 || (filterPriceFrom > 0 && filterPriceTo < 200000)` works just fine.

You show the anchor element when `filterPriceFrom` is `0` or `filterPriceFrom` is greater than zero and `filterPriceTo` is less than `200000`, correct?

Are you sure that `filterPriceTo` or `filterPriceFrom` is in `$scope`?
Take a look at the controller in the plunk please, do you have something similar?